# How to Cancel scheduled Message in Azure Topic

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

> As the title says, Is it possible to cancel scheduled message delivery to a
>   topic?

**Background:**

I am using [message scheduling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.scheduledenqueuetimeutc.aspx) in topic. I generally schedule the message delivery after 10 minutes.
It works fine. Based on certain business logic, I need to cancel a scheduled message. Is it feasible?

Answer (score 2):

From version 3.3.1 , you can now do this.

```
var sequenceNumber = await queueClient.ScheduleMessageAsync(message, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(300)).ConfigureAwait(false);
await queueClient.CancelScheduledMessageAsync(sequenceNumber).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't. Have look at this video - [Service Bus Messaging Deep-Dive](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Subscribe/Service-Bus-Messaging-Deep-Dive) around 1:36:50:

> It won't be visible other than accumulating in storage quota and you also can't cancel it

Your best option is to wait for the message, receive it and handle cancellation in the logic.